# How to autofill OpenOffice Math formula editor in OOo Calc?

Tags: math, macros, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, formula-editor

I am using OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet formulas with psuedo-random numbers to generate arrays of arithmetic problems which I can easily update to creating new worksheets (I'm a teacher)

Problems are output as formula mark-ups in string form. OOo Math formulas use these string commands typed into the editor to display nicely formatted maths expressions.

I can do this next step manually:

```
1) go to source cell and copy string mark-up to clipboard  
2) select target cell and clear existing contents and objects  
3) create new Math object anchored to target cell  
4) open Math editor window and paste in mark-up string  
5) exit Math editor window and return cursor to source cell
```

Result: a nice maths expression of given arithmetic problem.

I need to be able to do this for entire columns of source cells on various sheets. 
...even better, to then add a listener to dynamically update as sources are updated.

I found code here: [Cell content inside formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369279/cell-content-inside-formula) that achieves this for a fixed pair of cells, but despite all my best efforts, I have had to admit defeat - generalising this code is simply beyond my expertise!

The absolute ideal would be a macro function that I could call like a spreadsheet function; with input arguments (sourceCell, targetCell, listenerON/OFF) that could run the above algorithm and dynamically update if required.

Can anybody help me? A solution like this, or any kind of workaround would be immensely helpful.

---

UPDATE 2016/10/27

Thank you Jim K, that did work, but use of the dispacher comes with a whole host of difficulties I hadn't foreseen.
I just found [Charlie Young's post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=45282&p=209254&hilit=macro%20math%20editor#p209254) in the OpenOffice forum which makes use of the API. I have included my adaptation of his code below.

Can anybody help me to integrate it into a function in a similar way as I've described? I don't know how to solve placement of the Math object in to the target cell.

The API code is great as it will create a new Math object each time the code is updated. Existing ones do need to be deleted though.

I think the limitation of not being able to delete existing objects from within a function is going to persist. Would this be the case even if done by a subroutine called by the function?

```
function InsertFormula(paraFromCell, paraToCell)
   Dim oDoc As Object
   Dim oSheet As Object
   Dim oShape As Object

   oDoc = ThisComponent
   oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(0)

   oShape = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.OLE2Shape")
   oShape.CLSID = "078B7ABA-54FC-457F-8551-6147e776a997"

   oSheet.Drawpage.Add(oShape)
   oShape.Model.Formula = paraFromCell

   oShape.setSize(oShape.OriginalSize)
end function
```

---

NEXT UPDATE

I've been managing to solve my own problems quite quickly now...

I've decided to go with a sub, not a function, so I can access the sheet to delete existing objects. Code is attached - Source cells are in Column C and target cells in matching rows of Column A. So far I am only able to send objects to $A$1.

How do I anchor each new object to a specific cell?

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub InsertThisFormula

  Dim oDoc As Object
  Dim oSheet As Object
  Dim oShape As Object
  Dim sourceCell As Object
  Dim targetCell As Object

  oDoc = ThisComponent
  oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(1)

  Dim n As Integer
  n = 1 'number of rows of formulas

  for i = 0 To n-1
     rem loop through cells
     sourceCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(2, i)
     targetCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, i)

     rem clear target cell object/s
     targetCell.ClearContents(128)

     oShape = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.OLE2Shape")
     oShape.CLSID = "078B7ABA-54FC-457F-8551-6147e776a997"

     oSheet.Drawpage.Add(oShape)
     oShape.Model.Formula = sourceCell.string

     oShape.setSize(oShape.OriginalSize)

  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please remove `Solved` from your title, and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Mifeet's example, add this to `My Macros`:

```vb
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Creates a math formula from text
Function InsertFormulaFromCell(paramCellFrom, paramCellTo)
    dim document as object
    dim dispatcher as object
    document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

    rem go to cell containing markup and copy it
    dim fromCellArgs(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    fromCellArgs(0).Name = "ToPoint"
    fromCellArgs(0).Value = paramCellFrom
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, fromCellArgs())
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())

    rem go to cell where I want the formula displayed
    dim toCellArgs(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    toCellArgs(0).Name = "ToPoint"
    toCellArgs(0).Value = paramCellTo
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, toCellArgs())

    rem open Star.Math
    oDesk = createUnoService ("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertObjectStarMath", "", 0, Array())
    document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

    rem paste clipboard using Array() as place-holder for variable name
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Paste", "", 0, Array())

    rem exit Star.Math
    dispatcher.executeDispatch( _
        document, ".uno:TerminateInplaceActivation", "", 0, Array())
    InsertFormulaFromCell = "Math Formula updated " & Now()
End Function
```

To run it, put this formula in cell C5:

```
=INSERTFORMULAFROMCELL("$C$3","$C$20")
```

Now when the values get updated, it creates another formula.

Note: I could not get the `.uno:Delete` section of Mifeet's code to work, perhaps because functions are not supposed to access other cells.  This may require manually deleting the formulas before creating new ones.

Comment: Thank you Jim K! That does indeed work, but a whole lot of problems seem to have been introduced using the dispacher in this way.

I just came across
[this](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45282) post:

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45282
A much more elegant solution seemingly. Trying to get the same functionality out of it. Yet to be able to place the formula in target cell.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

This is now solved. After a lot of searching, I found what I needed! Simple really. Future improvements might be to resize cells appropriately. Happy for now. Thanks to Jim K and the rest of the Stack Overflow community!

Complete macro below:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

  Sub InsertThisFormula

  Dim oDoc As Object
  Dim oSheet As Object
  Dim oShape As Object
  Dim sourceCell As Object
  Dim targetCell As Object

  oDoc = ThisComponent
  oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(1)

  Dim n As Integer
  n = 6 'number of rows of formulas

  for i = 0 To n-1
     rem loop through cells
     sourceCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(2, i)
     targetCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(3, i)

     rem clear target cell object/s
     targetCell.ClearContents(128)

     oShape = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.OLE2Shape")
     oShape.CLSID = "078B7ABA-54FC-457F-8551-6147e776a997"

     oSheet.Drawpage.Add(oShape)
     oShape.Model.Formula = sourceCell.string

     oShape.setSize(oShape.OriginalSize)

     oShape.Anchor = targetCell
     oShape.MoveProtect = True

  Next i

End Sub
```